Callout with form-data from Salesforce Apex to Auth0

I have limited knowledge to use form-data for the request.
I created a body as
--usersjiaosd9821931-FGGHJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="users"; filename="users.json";

Content-Type: application/json

[{"email": "ian+3@gmail.com","password": "alwaysPostFakePasswords"}, {"email": "ian+4@gmail.com","password": "sdfnDAqpAdoQF&www344"}]
--usersjiaosd9821931-FGGHJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="connection_id"

con_test
--usersjiaosd9821931-FGGHJ--

From the screenshot, the user.json is [{"email": "ian+3@gmail.com","password": "alwaysPostFakePasswords"}, {"email": "ian+4@gmail.com","password": "alwaysPostFakePasswords"}]
I built something in Salesforce Apex like
HTTP http = new Http();
Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('The url to /api/v2/jobs/users-imports');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=--usersjiaosd9821931-FGGHJ');
request.setBody(body);
response = http.send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());

I keep getting {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Must provide 'users' file as multipart part.","errorCode":"invalid_body"}

This question is similar to: How can I compose a multipart/form-data request?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I found out the boundary in the header does not need to include the --. All good thanks.
